# After select the table from one server and how to insert into another server?

Tags: sql-server

I have two servers and I need to transfer all the details of a particular user from one server to another server.

I selected row from one server and now I have to insert into another server of a table.

I selected the row and I return it in datatable.

```
select * 
from [mp_Sites] 
where SiteID = "+siteid+"
```

I called the stored procedure which is present in the server2 for insert into the table which is selected from server1.

```
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

cmd.Parameters.Add("@1", SqlDbType.Int).Value = moduleId;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@2", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = dtEventsXmls.Rows[i]["SettingName"].ToString();
cmd.Parameters.Add("@3", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = dtEventsXmls.Rows[i]["SettingValue"].ToString();
cmd.Parameters.Add("@4", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = dtEventsXmls.Rows[i]["ControlType"].ToString();
cmd.Parameters.Add("@5", SqlDbType.NText).Value = dtEventsXmls.Rows[i] ["RegexValidationExpression"].ToString();
```

I think its complicated. Is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: So, what is complicated, and what is the question?

Answer (score 2):

You need to define linked server in SQl server.
For example LN that you can insert to the linked database.
LN.dbo.table . In your store procedure you can insert into linked table

Answer (score 0):

USE full qualified name like

```
        INSERT INTO  SERVER1.DATABASE1.dbo.TABLE1  values(SELECT * FROM SERVER2.DATABASE2.dbo.TABLE2)
```

make sure that  no. of columns and dataType should be same of those two tables and order of column value should be same .